# Is the characteristics function of a countable set is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]?$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

Is the characteristic function of a countable set Riemann-integrable on $[0,1]?$

**My attempt**: I think so

Take $\mathbb{1}_\mathbb{Q}$. We know  $m^*(\mathbb{Q})=0$ this implies   $\mathbb{1}_\mathbb{Q}$ is Riemann-integrable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Consider $\chi_{\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]}$. It is not Riemann integrable as each point of $[0,1]$ is a point of discontinuity since both $\Bbb Q,\Bbb R\backslash \Bbb Q$ are dense in $\Bbb R$. Note that Lebesgue measure of $[0,1]$ is $1$.  Here is the statement, which we want

> $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ is Riemann integrable if and only if set of points
> of discontinuity is a measure zero set.

You may also give an argument like this, $$U(P,\chi_{\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]})-L(P,\chi_{\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]})=1\text{ for every partition }P\text{ of }[0,1].$$

> Note that $\chi_{\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]}$ is Lebesgue integrable, with Lebesgue integral $0$ because it
> is almost equal to $0$ function, as you mentioned Lebesgue outer measure of $\Bbb Q$, hence Lebesgue measure of $\Bbb Q$ is zero.

**But note that $\chi_S$, where $S=\{0\}\cup\{1/n: n\in\Bbb N\}$ is Riemann Integrable on $[0,1]$, as the point of discontinuity of $\chi_S$ is exactly $S$, and Lebesgue measure of $S$ is zero.**

> Another nice example is that $$f(x)=\begin{cases}0 &\text{ if }x\text{
>  is irrational},\\ \frac{1}{q} & \text{ if }x=\frac{p}{q}\text{ with
>  }p\in\Bbb Z, q\in \Bbb N,\gcd(p,q)=1.\end{cases}$$
>
> This function **is Riemann integrable** on $[0,1]$ as each irrational
> point is a point of continuity of $f$.

Comment: ..@sumanta $m^*(\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1] ) =0$   which contradicts ur statement  that  if the set of point of discontinuity  is measure 0 set  , then according to  that statement it will be reimman integrable,

Comment: You are missing something. The set of points of discontinuity is measure zero set is necessary for Riemann integration.

Comment: You may also calculate the upper sum minus lower sum if you want.

Comment: Also, note that every Riemann integrable function is Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: Okks  ,@Sumanta  but  here im confusing ur answer that  according to ur  given theorem in answer box  it will be contradicts    see  what im thinking :$$\chi_ {\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]}=
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x\in{\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]}$} \\
0, & \text{if $x\notin {\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]}$}  \\
\end{cases}
$$

Here set of point of discontinuity is $\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]$ and it  have measure $0$ since $ m^*(\Bbb Q\cap[0,1])=0$

Comment: Take any point $x\in[0,1]$ we have two sequence $\big(\Bbb Q\cap [0,1]\big)\ni r_n\to x$ and $([0,1]\backslash\Bbb Q)\ni i_n\to x$. Then, $\chi_{\Bbb Q\cap [0,1]}(r_n)\to1$ but $\chi_{\Bbb Q\cap [0,1]}(i_n)\to 0$.

Comment: This is just because bout $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb R\backslash \Bbb Q$ are dense in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: okss thanks u  got it now @Sumanta